# Http Live Streaming Delay on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, linux, stream, vlc

With this code I see the stream of my desktop in a iPhone:

```
vlc -I dummy screen:// vlc://quit --sout=&#039;#transcode{threads=300,width=554,height=367,fps=30,vcodec=h264,vb=500000,venc=x264{aud,profile=baseline,level=30,keyint=30,bframes=0,ref=1}}:duplicate{dst=std{access=livehttp{seglen=10,delsegs=true,numsegs=100,index=/var/www/streaming/mystream.m3u8,index-url=http://localhost/streaming/mystream-########.ts},mux=ts{use-key-frames},dst=/var/www/streaming/mystream-########.ts}};
```

but I have a big delay, like 30-40 second... Do you know how to reduce this delay?

All I want is:

• Stream clearly the desktop for a 600x400 window in a iPhone

• No audio

• MAX delay of 1-2 second

Do you know how to do a stream?

Comment: Have you used synchronous or Asynchronous method of connection.

Comment: I connect thought a wifi lan...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best stream I get is from ffmpeg, but there is always 7-8 seconds of delay.
This is the string:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s `xdpyinfo | grep 'dimensions:'|awk '{print $2}'` -r 25 -i :0.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -r 25 -profile:v baseline -b:v 1500k -x264opts keyint=25 -s 640x360 -map 0 -flags -global_header -f segment -segment_list index_1500.m3u8 -segment_time 1 -segment_format mpeg_ts -segment_list_type m3u8 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_list_size 1 segment%05d.ts
```